# angularjs directive use controller as vm instead of scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular2-styleguide

I am attempting to create a directive. I have been following the john papa opinionated style guide and using controller as vm. unfortunately when I attempt to make a directive I am unsure how to do it without using $scope instead of vm.

(the last tag should say angularjs-styleguide but I couldn't find one and I don't have enough points to make a new tag)

here is the plunkr.
https://plnkr.co/edit/DYTJURgaLd0QadcCSPFW?p=preview

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
<script src="./directive.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
       <div unordered-list="products" list-property="price | currency"></div>
       <!-- this does not work
       <div unordered-list="vm.products" list-property="price | currency"></div>
       -->
    </div> 
</div>
```

controller

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);

  myCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

   function myCtrl($scope){
       /* jshint validthis: true */
       var vm=this;
        $scope.products = [
            { name: "Apples", category: "Fruit", price: 1.20, expiry: 10 },
            { name: "Bananas", category: "Fruit", price: 2.42, expiry: 7 },
            { name: "Pears", category: "Fruit", price: 2.02, expiry: 6 },
        ];

        vm.products =  [
            { name: "Apples", category: "Fruit", price: 1.20, expiry: 10 },
            { name: "Bananas", category: "Fruit", price: 2.42, expiry: 7 },
            { name: "Pears", category: "Fruit", price: 2.02, expiry: 6 },
        ];
   } 

})();
```

directive

```
angular.module("myApp")
    .directive("unorderedList", function () {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.data = scope[attrs["unorderedList"]];
            },
            restrict: "A",
            template: "<ul><li ng-repeat='item in data'>"
            + "{{item.price | currency}}</li></ul>",
            replace: true
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify `scope: { data: '=unorderedList' }` in your directive, angular will automatically pull the value of `vm.products` into the directive's scope and it will be available under the `data` variable. Also, there is no need for the `link()` function.

```
angular.module("myApp")
    .directive("unorderedList", function () {
        return {
            scope: { data: '=unorderedList' },
            restrict: "A",
            template: "<ul><li ng-repeat='item in data'>"
            + "{{item.price | currency}}</li></ul>",
            replace: true
        };
    });
```